# i have declared variable with function and i would like to call that variable in onclick event

Tags: jquery, onclick

i have declared variable with function like below

```
var config = function () {
    this.page.url = "http://localhost/test/echowrite_code.html"; 
    this.page.identifier = "this is the first post";
};

 //i would like to get the config variable values in on click function
$('#sendComment').on('click', function(){
 console.log("url:"+config.page.url);
  console.log("identifier :"+config.page.identifier);
});
```

getting output:

```
url:undefined
identifier:undefined
```

but expected output is:

```
url:http://localhost/test/echowrite_code.html
identifier: this is the first post
```

but i am not getting the values what i am expecting

Comment: _but i am not getting the values what i am expecting_ 1. What value are you getting? 2. What value are you expecting?

Comment: Why is `config` a function?

Comment: And what is `this.page` supposed to be? If you want to use `this` in a function, it should normally be in an object or prototype.

Comment: config variable defined in .html file.
onclick function will be in some other JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create an object

```js
var config = {
    page : {
      url : "http://localhost/test/echowrite_code.html",
      identifier : "this is the first post"
    }
};

 //i would like to get the config values in on click function
$('#sendComment').on('click', function(){
 console.log(config.page.url);
  console.log(config.page.identifier);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="sendComment">Click</button>
```

Comment: That's just an object, nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

you can return the object from a function and use it if u want it.

```
var config = function () {
   var page={
       url : "http://localhost/test/echowrite_code.html"; 
       identifier : "this is the first post";
   }
   return page;
};
```

then in the code

```
$('#sendComment').on('click', function(){
 console.log(config().url);
  console.log(config().identifier);
 });
```